# ExecutorCompletionService.take() method in distributed environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, singleton

I am trying to implement `ExecutorCompletionService` in a `WebServer` that would be having multiple hosts and would be called from multiple clients.

My question is related to the implementation of the `ExecutorCompletionService.take()` method. My declaration of `ExecutorCompletionService` is a singleton with fixed pool size of 20 threads as part of spring injected beans.

Now suppose this scenario:

1. From Instance 1 of method call: I submit 5 tasks to the service to work upon.
2. From Instance 2 of method call: I submit 6 tasks to the service in parallel from other client.
3. From Instance 1: I call `executorCompletionService.take()` 5 times.

Is there any guarantee that I would get the values corresponding to the tasks submitted in instance 1 when calling from the same instance?

Note that I am just cancelling the task at then end and my fixed thread pool always remain alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line from the docs about `ExecutorCompletionService` is key:

> The class is lightweight enough to be suitable for transient use when
>   processing groups of tasks

In other words, it is lightweight enough to make this a request scoped object or even as a local variable or field.

So you shouldn't really make this a singleton, because as you suspected, it won't differentiate between tasks submitted from one request/thread or another.

Instead, make the `Executor` a singleton and share that for all your `ExecutorCompletionService`s.

**Update**

```
@Inject private Executor executor;  // can be singleton

public void someMethod() {
    ExecutorCompletionService ecs1 = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);
    ExecutorCompletionService ecs2 = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);

    // ExecutorCompletionService should be scoped per instance

    ecs1.submit(task1)
    ecs1.submit(task2);
    ecs1.submit(task3);

    ecs2.submit(task4)
    ecs2.submit(task5);
    ecs2.submit(task6);

    // ecs1 `take` will only return tasks submitted to ecs1
    // ecs2 `take` will only return tasks submitted to ecs2

}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by making Executor as Singleton? How would it help to get those particular future values?

Comment: The executor can be shared amongst the ExecutorCompletionServices.  You get the correct values because you will have multiple of those services.

Comment: Why is it that making executor singleton would work? I mean to say this
Let's make executor singleton with 20 threads, now we still have these 20 threads to work with. Now we would instantiate CompletionService in each of those thread pool. Same case might happen again, instance 1 gives the 5 tasks and instance 2 gives 5 tasks for the same executor. Now using take() method, we might end up getting one of the task from the other instance. How can having multiple services avoid this? Do each service keeps track of future it has submitted to the executor or listens till first task is found?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the Executor is, the point is you have multiple ExecutorCompletionService which **could** share the same executor.  A completion service does not have its own pool, they have an Executor, so they share a pool if you use the same Executor.  If instance 1 uses ExecutorCompletionService #1, then `take` will only return tasks from instance 1.  Instance 2 uses their own instance of an ExecutorCompletionService.

Comment: This is what I wanted to confirm. I couldn't find any doc for this. I believe implementation and proper logging would also confirm your hypothesis.
Thanks